# IBM BPM 8.5.7 upgrade to 8.6

Tags: ibm-bpm

I'm going to upgrade our IBM BPM 8.5.7 server, and IBM Installation manager suggests to upgrade to IBM Business Automation Workflow.

Is it correct ? IBM BPM became IBM BAW ? Is it the same licence ?

As don't have any other alternative on the upgrade options.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you should always check with your IBM Rep, but IBM BAW is has subsumed IBM BPM in their offerings.  That is you can no longer buy just IBM BPM.  Your license for IBM BPM should convert to an IBM BAW license.

[This article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610883) articulates the various upgrade paths.  If you have the option of going to BAW I would advise doing so.  From what I remember they announced at Think last year, going from BPM -> BAW is straight forward from a licensing standpoint.  However if you are coming from Case Manager it is more complex as I think CM had a per seat or per user pricing model, and BAW follows the PVU licensing model (hardware based approach) which is the same approach followed for IBM BPM licenses.

One important note - as of 8.6 the desktop designer has been depreciated.  You will need to plan to convert all of your legacy desktop assets over to Web Process Designer assets as the Eclipsed based designer is being phased out.  I think that BAW only supports the Web Based Designer (but please check before assuming I'm correct).

Comment: Yes, the IBM support told me that generally who are entitled to BPM are also entitled to BAW, since BPM was merged into BAW 18+ and future updates and fixes will be delivered via BAW.

Comment: Desktop process designer is still there. In BAW, it no longer requires separate licences.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8JB4_18.0.0/com.ibm.wbpm.workflow.main.doc/topics/cbpm_ae.html

Comment: @Drux I tested upgrade in my LAB, and there still is a Desktop designer (deprecated) in BAW v18. It is the same used in 8.5.7. But allow you download from Workflow Center. Would be a huge work to upgrade all processes from 8.5.6 version to v18.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
as Drux said, it is the same license,
but not only, as starting from 8.6.0 you can use advanced features under the same license:

https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&appname=gpateam&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS217-379

IBM BPM V8.6 delivers product simplification to utilize its full power more easily and provide greater flexibility.
**Standard and Advanced editions are now combined into a single offering, where Process Center, Process Server, and PFS are included under a single license.**
Web Process Designer in IBM BPM V8.6 no longer requires a separate charge.
Desktop Process Designer V8.5.7 supports IBM BPM V8.6 and is licensed separately with an additional charge.
IBM BPM Express® is also available if clients need a low cost, entry point on-premise offering.
Clients can also subscribe to IBM BPM on Cloud, if they prefer IBM to host and manage the IBM BPM infrastructure on their behalf.